# How to call a cs function in another library with ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Im working with the model view/Controller, so im trying to keep files in different folders like this
[image]

Im trying to call a c# class on the Business folder from the Boleta proyect with ajax within a aspx like this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Business/SaveExpenses.cs/save",
    data:  JSON.stringify({ questions: questions}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("fail");
    }
});
```

The c# file that im trying to call looks like this.

```
namespace Business
{
    public class SaveExpenses
    {
        public string save(string foo)
        {
            string ret= "something";
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

When the page is executed and goes through the ajax function it throws an error 404 not found.
Now my question is, how do I navigate the folders in asp.net? or the correct way of calling the function.
Im comming from a php environment and im pretty new to asp.net so i will gladly take any suggestions

Comment: That's not how it works. You can't just create a class and have a method and expect it to be publicly exposed. You need to pick something that can get routed to, some sort of endpoint that gets exposed. Generally the way this is done is by having a [Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api) controller sit in front of your logic. You configure routing for the controller so that requests hit an action method, which then passes that request off to some other class in your business logic. The Web API will also take care of serializing, deserializing your passed objects and returned values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This url is wrong:

> url: "Business/SaveExpenses.cs/save"

The URL should refer to the actual route. For example:

```
public class BusinessController : Controller
{
    // GET
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public string Save()
    {
        string ret= "something";
        return ret;
    }
```

Then your URL would be `Business/Save`(subject to RouteConfig etc considerations).

Comment: You're assuming he's got a controller here.

Comment: @mason Literally the first line of the question: "Im working with the model view/Controller"

Comment: That indicates to me that he believes he's using ASP.NET MVC. But `SaveExpenses` isn't a controller, and doesn't even appear to be inside the MVC project. You're on the right path, I'd just show how you would call functionality in `SaveExpenses` from the controller.

Comment: I mean, there's lots of ways he can call his function from another file (static method, or create an instance of an object and call from there, SaveExpenses.save("foo"), etc). I guess my answer was to say that he should be putting that sort of logic in his controller in the first place.

Comment: No, putting the logic in a controller is the opposite of what you want to do. Controllers should be lightweight, a simple facade in front of your actual logic. Controllers should handle taking input from the web and getting a response back to it. The actual logic should be handled elsewhere. This avoids tight coupling to your controller framework, and makes it easier to support new paradigms as they come up.

Comment: Im working with tbe MVC ideology, not with ASP.NET MVC, so from what im understanding I need to add a controller that is going to be in charge of calling `SaveExpenses`?

Comment: @cafej I would recommend actually implementing an MVC project instead of trying to create your own, and consulting a tutorial to get started: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview

Comment: @cafej ASP.NET Web API would be better suited to responding to AJAX calls than ASP.NET MVC (although either would work)

Comment: Ok, thank you both for your directions, im going to invest time in researching ASP.NET wep API

Comment: @cafej thats fine you have accepted this answer, but i'd encourage you toat least give mine a look. It's a leaner approach and will land you in the right direction for basic server CRUD operations

Answer (score 0):

look into [Adding a Web API Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations#adding-a-web-api-controller). basically, your ajax call will hit a http endpoint in which you'll execute your server side logic there.

The following is just a generic pattern - you'll need to implement a bit more [plumbing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) to get this functional...

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/Business/Expenses', // http route
  // [...]
});
```

---

```
[RoutePrefix("Business")]
public class ExpensesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Save([FromBody] string questions)
    {
        // do stuff
        return Ok("something");
    }
}
```

Comment: To implement this, I just need to add the ExpensesController controler to the Boleta project?

Comment: No, you'll need to create a web API project and follow the documentation I have provided. It's a big topic that will take effort to understand and apply. I'm surprised you have accepted the answer without even applying it to your situation...

Answer (score 0):

In Boleta project add the namespace of business

```
using Business;
```

then create one action in controller into Boleta Project

```
public JsonResult Save(param)
{
SaveExpenses se = new SaveExpenses();
    var result=  se.Save(param);
    return json(result);
}
```

and call save() action through ajax